# Regex Extract html Body

Tags: c#, vb.net, regex

How would I use Regex to extract the body from a html doc,
taking into account that the html and body tags might be in uppercase, lowercase or might not exist?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356340/regular-expression-to-extract-html-body-content ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't use a regular expression for this - use something like the [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net).

> This is an agile HTML parser that
>   builds a read/write DOM and supports
>   plain XPATH or XSLT (you actually
>   don't HAVE to understand XPATH nor
>   XSLT to use it, don't worry...). It is
>   a .NET code library that allows you to
>   parse "out of the web" HTML files. The
>   parser is very tolerant with "real
>   world" malformed HTML. The object
>   model is very similar to what proposes
>   System.Xml, but for HTML documents (or
>   streams).

Then you can extract the `body` with an XPATH.

Comment: I agree. I've used this and must say it's fast, neat and clean.

Answer (score 14):

How about something like this?

It captures everything between `<body></body>` tags (case insensitive due to `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`) into a group named `theBody`.

`RegexOptions.Singleline` allows us to handle multiline HTML as a single string.

If the HTML does not contain `<body></body>` tags, the `Success` property of the match will be false.

```
        string html;

        // Populate the html string here

        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline;
        Regex regx = new Regex( "<body>(?<theBody>.*)</body>", options );

        Match match = regx.Match( html );

        if ( match.Success ) {
            string theBody = match.Groups["theBody"].Value;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I strive for.

Comment: Great, that does exactly what I needed.

Comment: A good simple solution, but beware of body tags with spaces or attributes: < body id='content'> would not match

Answer (score 0):

This should get you pretty close:

```
(?is)<body(?:\s[^>]*)>(.*?)(?:</\s*body\s*>|</\s*html\s*>|$)
```

Comment: Please provide detail solution.