# Trying to select a 'body' tag from html that is returned by get() request

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm making an [ajax get call](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) that returns me contents of html page. I'm trying to select contents of the `body` tag but my selector returns an empty jquery object.

```
$.get(filename, function(data) {
    console.log($("body", data));
})
```

where `data` is contents of html file.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356340/regular-expression-to-extract-html-body-content

Use a regex call to get the contents of the body tag.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

jQuery cannot select `body` of the response string, because the `<body>` tag disappears when the string is converted using `$()`.

Hence, you have to select the body from the `data` string in another way, such as Regular expressions. Example:

```
$.get(filename, function(data) {
    var body = data.replace(/^[\S\s]*<body[^>]*?>/i, "")
                    .replace(/<\/body[\S\s]*$/i, "");
    //Optionally, convert the string to a jQuery object:
    body = $(body);
    console.log(body);
}))
```

Note: My Regular Expression assumed a wellformed HTML document, where `>` are correctly shown using HTML entities. If this is not the case, more advanced RegExps has to be used, such as the ones shown at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474710/can-i-load-an-entire-html-document-into-a-document-fragment-in-internet-explorer/7539198#7539198).

Comment: wonder if it would be easier to load the contents into xml document and use selectors to grab body tag. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Comment: @dev.e.loper Definitely, **when the returned HTML is a *well-formed* HTML document**.

Comment: Just so others know, after I append this body (using jQuery append) I have to wait a little (via setTimeOut function) in order to perform any selection operations on the elements that were just appended.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery uses the document object model, not the "text" that makes up that model. You only have a big piece of text in the data element that hasn't been added to the document yet.

```
$(body).html(data);
```

... assuming the data contains valid body code. It it's an entire HTML page, then you'll need to parse it for just the body content, e.g. using indexOf or somesuch.