# .find() in $.ajax response

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm just doing a simple ajax request to get the content of a file, but when I try to grab the actual `<body>` it always returns nothing.

```
jQuery.ajax(location).done(function(response) {
    // RETURNS []
    console.log(jQuery(response).find('body'));

    // <body class="html ...">
    // RETURNS []
    console.log(jQuery(response).find('.html'));

    // When I try to get any other div it just works
    // RETURNS THE DIV
    console.log(jQuery(response).find('#header'));
})
```

Comment: What is the actual data that response contain?

Comment: Just the full html from a website `<html><head></head><body>...` So the source code

Comment: Is `location` on the same domain as your page?

Comment: Yes it is, just to be clear, I'm getting the actual content of the file, the .find() method is just not working to get the content of the `<body>`, I can however search for any id or class.

Comment: Does logging `jQuery(response).html()` give the expected result?

Comment: `jQuery(response).html()` just returns `null`

Comment: Take a look here, it's the same issue with a solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839889/trying-to-select-a-body-tag-from-html-that-is-returned-by-get-request

Answer (score 1):

*jQuery(response)* strips away the **html**, **head** and **body** tags

you need to wrap your body content in an extra div and look for it.

edit:

jQuery(*string*) parse the string to check if it is a selector or a html fragment. if it's a html fragment the string is injected into an empty div which *do not* support **html**, **head** and **body** tags hence they are *stripped* away.

Comment: If I use console.log, i can see the html, head and body tags in there, it's not stripped away

Comment: you can see the tags in the response variable, but **jQuery** strips them away.