# Replacing entire page via AJAX causes Permission Denied error in IE only

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have an AJAX post that retrieves data from the server and either replaces part of the page or in some cases the full page.  This is controlled by a javascript fullRefresh parameter.  The problem is the refresh code works find in Firefox but causes a Permission Denied error in the bowels of JQuery after it runs in IE although it would appear to actually replace the page contents successfully.

IE version 11.0.9600.16659

JQuery version 1.8.2

```
Error message
Unhandled exception at line 2843, column 3 in http://localhost:62761/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js

0x800a0046 - JavaScript runtime error: Permission denied
```

My code is

```
function RefreshScreenContent(formActionUrl, formHTML, fullRefresh) {

    fullRefresh = (typeof fullRefresh === "undefined") ? false : fullRefresh;

    if (fullRefresh) {
        document.write(formHTML);
        document.close();
    }
    else {
        $("#content-parent").html(formHTML);
    }


}
```

The partial refreshes work fine but the full refreshes are the problem.  I have tried hardcoding the document.write call to write a well formed simple html page rather than formHTML in case that was somehow the problem but even a simple single word page causes the error.

The actual error occurs a some point later with a callback inside JQuery.

The AJAX post to the server is in the same application i.e. is not a cross domain request.  I have seen posts online talking aboue cross domain stuff that is not applicable here.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how to stop it?  Is there an alternative IE way of replacing the page contents?

Comment: Could it not be that the document no longer exists and "full refresh" is trying to still access it.  Try to skip the "        document.close();" and see what happens.  If it doesn't leak, then essentially you're good.

Comment: It may be in same domain as you said, but also port numbers should match. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: @AnthonyHorne The document.close() didn't make a difference

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL would that not cause an error in Firefox though?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine (at least at first glance). My guess is that you make the call in such a way, that it is interpreted as cross-domain.

I would suggest checking:

- http vs https (most common)
- the destination port
- the root url
- maybe the "destination" page makes some requests of its own, check to be on same domain

The reason why IE may be the only one with the problem is that it has higher security demanding by default that other browsers (check advanced security settings - can't remember where they are put in menu) so it interprets requests in a more "paranoid" manor.

I repeat, what I said is just a guess, based on cases I've been put into.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used the approach here to replace the body tag in the pgae with the one in the markup the AJAX receives back https://stackoverflow.com/a/7839921/463967

I would have preferred to replace all content not just the body but I can always adapt later to include the header etc as body is enough for my uses right now. This works in IE and Firefox.